# %load command in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, load, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am trying to execute %load command in my Jupyter notebook, but it doesn't work as expected. Instead of getting the content of the module I want to load, I get a dictionary with information about the module:

```
# %load test.ipynb
{
 "cells": [
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": 5,
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [
    {
     "name": "stdout",
     "output_type": "stream",
     "text": [
      "2.3333333333333335\n"
     ]
    }
   ],
   "source": [
    "def example(a, b, c):\n",
    "    return (a+b)/c\n",
    "\n",
    "x = 12\n",
    "y = -5\n",
    "z = 3\n",
    "\n",
    "result = example(x, y, z)\n",
    "print(result)"
   ]
  },
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": null,
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [],
   "source": []
  }
 ],
 "metadata": {
  "kernelspec": {
   "display_name": "Python 3",
   "language": "python",
   "name": "python3"
  },
  "language_info": {
   "codemirror_mode": {
    "name": "ipython",
    "version": 3
   },
   "file_extension": ".py",
   "mimetype": "text/x-python",
   "name": "python",
   "nbconvert_exporter": "python",
   "pygments_lexer": "ipython3",
   "version": "3.6.5"
  }
 },
 "nbformat": 4,
 "nbformat_minor": 2
}
```

This is what I expect to get (it is an example from 'Data Analysis with Python' book):

```
%load test.ipynb    
def example(a, b, c):
    return (a+b)/c

x = 12
y = -5
z = 3

result = example(x, y, z)
print(result)
```

Does anyone know why this example doesn't work?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The magic function `%load` is loading the file you specified correctly. What you are seeing is the `json` format of an `.ipnb` file.

If you want to load a pythin module into a cell to execute it, you must loat a `.py` file containing valid python.

for instance:

```
%load myawesomescript.py
```

You can also load `.txt`, `.csv`, and other formats too.

Comment: Where is the contents of `myawesomescript.py` loaded into?  The global namespace?